# How to use BatchedNMS plugin with retinaFace Detector

Tags: tensorrt

I am using RetinaFaceNet for facial detection, which provides a score, a bounding box, and 5 facial landmarks for each detected face. These are represented as three separate vectors (or matrices): a score vector, a bounding box vector, and a landmark vector. I would like to apply non-maximum suppression (NMS) to filter out overlapping bounding boxes based on the scores, which is a common post-processing step in object detection.

I am considering using the BatchedNMS Plugin in TensorRT for this task, as it provides an efficient, GPU-accelerated implementation of NMS. However, I am encountering a problem. While the BatchedNMS Plugin can provide the retained bounding boxes and their scores after NMS, it does not maintain a linkage to the original indices of these bounding boxes in the input data.

This presents a challenge because I need to keep track of the facial landmarks associated with each bounding box. After applying NMS, I don’t know how to find the corresponding landmarks for the retained bounding boxes, as the original indices are lost in the process.

I am looking for suggestions on how I can maintain the linkage between bounding boxes and their corresponding landmarks through the NMS process. Specifically, how can I find the corresponding landmarks for the bounding boxes retained after NMS when using the BatchedNMS Plugin in TensorRT? Any advice or alternative strategies would be greatly appreciated.

Attached, you’ll find a screenshot of the model’s structure. The screenshot was created with the Netron tool.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have struggled with a similar problem, but unfortunately never found an acceptable solution. As per my knowledge, none of the optimized TensorRT NMS plugins currently support tracking prediction indices from the original tensor.
I ended up using the standard ONNX `NonMaxSuppression` operator, for which TensorRT creates a `Myelin` subgraph. Throughput of the engine suffered significantly, though.

This was last autumn, so if anyone else has more up to date information on this, I'd be also very interested to hear.

Comment: Appreciate you sharing your insights! From what I've discovered, creating a universal Non-Maximum Suppression (NMS) for models like RetinaFace might be challenging. This is primarily due to RetinaFace's unique mechanism of using 'priors' in decoding output, which sets it apart from other models. However, I've wrote a custom NMS implementation using CUDA and it seems to work well(I don't like to use onnx as much as possible). The complete inference time is about just 3 milliseconds, delivering the results I was hoping for.

Comment: Nice! Thank you for the update, going to revisit my old implementation as well now.  Did you have to write the custom NMS from scratch, or was it possible to extend the `BatchedNMS` plugin? Also, is there a reason you avoid using ONNX - are there some unwanted interactions between TensorRT and onnx graphs?

Comment: I created it all myself(found some codes for it, but none of them worked for me). I studied the Python code to understand the decoding process. I did this because I didn't want multiple inference engines in my code, and I couldn't figure out how to use the ONNX engine directly with CUDA memory.